# Call Visio POLYLINE function with variable list of coordinates

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm trying to design a Visio 2010 shape whose geometry depends on the shape's width. That is, the number and the length of the segments that make up the shape's geometry depends on the width.

Instead of creating a LineTo row (in the geometry section of the ShapeSheet) for each segment, I was thinking of calling the POLYLINE function from a PolyLineTo row. Is there a way to use a list of coordinates that comes from another cell with this function, e.g.:

```
POLYLINE(1, 1, Scratch.A1)
```

I've tried this with a coordinates list in the form of a string in Scratch.A1 ("5mm, 0mm, 5mm, 5mm"), but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this (having multiple values in cell) is supported.

I believe your only alternative it to use multiple cells to hold each X and Y

For example:

```
POLYLINE(1,1,2,3,Scratch.X1,Scratch.Y1)
```

This, of course, is more complicated that using multiple **LineTo** rows.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I've used in the past is to dynamically build the entire POLYLINE formula as a string and push it into your target cell as required.  Have a look at the following post where I built a Sparkline shape using this technique:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2009/05/simple-visio-sparkline-implementation.html

Comment: Nice. Would it help to spell it out a bit more? Looks like your technique is to build a formula for the polyline as `User.PolySet =DEPENDSON(Scratch.B12)+SETF(GetRef(Geometry2.A2),"=POLYLINE("&Scratch.B12&")")`. Can you elaborate on where Scratch.B12 gets its value?

Comment: The sparkline shape in the above post supports up to 12 points, which the user can enter as an array of values in the shape data window.  There's a scratch row for each one of these values.  Column A decides whether to include the respective row.  If that's true then column B is just a concatenation of the calculated xy values from columns C and D.  So Scratch.B12 is the final concatenated result.  In fact you don't really need that DEPENDSON function as there's already a cell dependency (Scratch.B12) in the formula and the SETF will be fired every time Scratch.B12 changes.

Comment: In terms of the original question the point is that it's up to you on what basis you create your string, just as long as you push the entire formula in at the end.